# Zend Framework relationships - defining column names in findManyToManyRowset()?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table, relationships

I'm working on an application developed using Zend Framework. I have defined relationships in models, and can use them happily, e.g:

```
$rowset = $row->findManyToManyRowset('People', 'Jobs');
```

However, i've hit a problem where the rowset is returned has column names that are the same in 'People' and 'Jobs', and therefore, merges the array keys, losing some of the data from the final rowset.

I understand I can pass a `Zend_Db_Select` object to `findManyToManyRowset()` as one of the parameters, but can't find any documentation explaining how to use it in this case, e.g.:

```
$select = $this->select()->from(array(
                                     'p' => 'people', 
                                     'j' => 'jobs'
                                     ),
                                array( 
                                     'person_id' => 'p.id',
                                     'job_id' => 'j.id',
                                     'person_code' => 'p.code',
                                     'job_code' => 'j.code'
                                     )
                                );
```

If i try to use the above code, I get a message such as:

```
Error: No reference rule "" from table People to table Jobs
```

Can anyone enlighten me on how this should be done? I know I could change my column names in the database, but i'd prefer a code change as opposed to re-designing my DB structure and updating all the related code.

Note: without some form of column aliasing as above, the rowset returned looks like this (ie., it merges the columns with the same names):

```
[_data:protected] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [code] => SX342
    )
```

Cheers,
  Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first recommendation is that you shouldn't name columns such generic names like `id` and `code`.  These names are meaningless, and as you have discovered they also result in collisions when you fetch results in an associative array.

You're also using the Select interface incorrectly.  You should specify only one table per `from()` call or `join()` call.

Finally, I never try to do complex queries via the `Zend_Db_Table` relationships interface.  It's intended only for simple cases.  If you have a more complex query, just write the SQL query explicitly.

See also [How to do a joined query in the ZF tables interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412799/how-to-do-a-joined-query-in-the-zf-tables-interface/1423381#1423381)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Bill. Do you have any recommendations for how the columns should be named, or on a wider scale, recommendations for good tutorials on database design best practices?

Comment: For example, you could use "person_id" in both tables, instead of "person_id" in one table and "id" in another table.  Where possible, make columns with the same content have the same name across tables.  Likewise "person_code" instead of simply "code".  Basically, make column names distinct across tables, at least when they are tables likely to be joined together in a query.

Comment: Read the first chapter of "Joe Celko's SQL Programming Style for Smarties."  Google Books includes chapter one in its online preview:  http://books.google.com/books?id=a9jtyioHfp8C

Comment: person.id is not meaningless, imho

Answer (score 2):

I know this answer comes a little late but here are some things to point out.

1) `findManyToManyRowset($matchTable, $intersectionTable, $callerRefRule, $matchRefRule, $select);`  -- if you are passing a `Zend_Db_Table_Select` you are going to want to pass `null` for the rules.

2) The `Zend_Db_Table_Select` passed into the `findManyToManyRowset()` should be created from `$matchTable` and it is safe to assume that in the where clauses `i` is the alias for the intersection table, and `m` is the alias for the match table.

3) In the case of collisions, `m` will win the key name in the associative array returned in php. The query executed looks like this:

```
  SELECT 
    `i`.*, `m`.* 
  FROM 
    `interscetTable` AS `i` 
  INNER JOIN 
    `matchTable` AS `m` 
  ON
    `i`.`fk_m` = `m`.`pk` WHERE (`i`.`fk_o` = ?)
```

4) No matter what, The return value of `findManyToManyRowset()` will be a Rowset created from the `$matchTable` so, if you need to capture any information from the intersecting table, while also capturing the data for the match table, you will probably need to have a custom `Zend_Db_Select` and avoid using the `Zend_Db_Table` stuff to map the data anyway.

So a working example, using "People" as the match table, "Workers" as the intersection table and lets say "Clients" as the originating table.. Assuming for this example that the tables link together something like:
 People.`id:...` -> workers.`person_id:client_id:job_id` -> clients:`id:...`

```
$client = $clientTable->fetchRow(); /// grab a random client

// fetch all people that have worked for the client ordered by their last name.
$client->findManyToManyRowset("People", "Workers", null, null, 
  $peopleTable->select()->order('m.lastname')); 

// fetch all people that have worked for the client ordered by their hire date:
// `workers`.`hiredate`
$client->findManyToManyRowset("People", "Workers", null, null, 
  $peopleTable->select()->order('i.hiredate'));
```